# How to create app with electron like steam-overlay

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to create electron application that will be game helper and it will show some cheats top on the any game while user plays. You can imagine like "Steam" application overlay in the game. I tried to open my application to the top and also try to show native dialogs & alerts to get app to top but os always hide game app (minimized) before show my app. My question is; is it possible to run or should i stop to try?

I added example code that i tried below.

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, shell, dialog } from 'electron';
import Positioner from 'electron-positioner';

app.on('ready', function () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      x: mainWindowState.x,
      y: mainWindowState.y,
      width: mainWindowState.width,
      height: mainWindowState.height,
      alwaysOnTop: true
   });

  //...some codes

  var ret = globalShortcut.register('shift+ctrl+x', function() {
    console.log('shift+ctrl+x is pressed');
    shell.beep();
    positioner.move('bottomRight');
    mainWindow.show();
  });
});
```

Comment: is this working for you

Answer (score 0):

It should be working, depend on the game engine and os, i tried the code here on osx and it work as expected. 
But want do you mean with "but os always hide game app (minimized) before show my app"
At all you start the app and then the game, and the app should overlay the game